# angular.js $scope.$broadcast, $scope.$emit, $rootScope.$broadcast what to use?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast

I'm building a search directive which I want multiple other directives of my application to be able to listen for changes to the text search.

I am trying to understand the difference between broadcast and emit, and what is best to suit my purposes.

As I understand it, the difference between $broadcast and $emit is that $broadcast goes down the scope tree only, and that $emit goes up the scope tree.

Up to this point I've been using $rootScope.$broadcast for my events, which for the most part have been global in scope.
Is this the right way of doing things? 
Should I be concerned if I have too many rootScope.$broadcast events? Or is that a non-issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't inject `$rootScope` all over the place. It can often becomes a crutch and you'll end up having a lot of "global variables"

I'd either build a service that abstracts the `$rootScope.broadcast` call, or simply use databinding instead:

```
<my-directive text-search="foo"></my-directive>
```

with a controller like:

```
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
  return {
    link: function($element, $scope, $attrs) {
      $scope.$watch($attrs.textSearch, function(newValue, oldValue) {

        // Do stuff here...

      });
    }    
  };
}]);
```

Comment: interesting idea @mmattax, with respect to you directive above, are you suggesting that I would have a text-search attribute on my search-box that I could then link to other directives? You put it as `text-search='foo'` but I'd want to pass a value to anything listening for search, so I'm not sure how the example you provided accomplishes that.

Comment: @pedalpete You'd have a search box that uses ng-model to publish the search text on the scope (that's what "foo" is in my example). Other directives would simply watch for changes.